# Nonparametric 2-way ANOVA for data with unequal n's due to possibly informative missingness

Tags: anova, nonparametric, missing-data, friedman-test

So my problem revolves around trying to find the right test for my data in R. I've been doing an experiment that is measuring sublethal effects in a toxic environment, and as a result, even though I started with the same numbers for all groups, my sample numbers have shifted due to mortality, leaving me with groups that have different numbers of data points. I've been trying to do nonparametric tests because the data distribution isn't normal, but can't do Friedman's due to the differences in number of data points. I essentially want something like a nonparametric two way ANOVA.

If you want more specifics I have 3 species that I work with: Chione, Venerupis, and Musculista. I exposed all these species to three different copper exposure levels: 0 ppb, 25 ppb, or 50 ppb. For this particular problem, I'm comparing their mucus production. So, independent variables are copper exposure and species, dependent variable is mucus production. Due to the deaths, they all have different numbers of survivors and therefore different numbers of data points. I want to be able to compare them, and would normally use a ANOVA, but they aren't distributed normally.

The mucus data is already transformed because it was a ratio to begin with (mucus/dry mass ratio), and was transformed via arcsine. The mucus collection procedure is fatal, so it's one value per mollusk. The differences in the data sets arise from the number of mollusks that were able to be tested in each group. For example, the 50 ppb groups high the highest mortality rates, so I was only able to collect mucus from a handful in comparison to the 0 ppb groups.

Comment: Mucus sounds positive, it might be possible to transform it to normality via something like the log. Do you have repeated measures? Even if you had normal data, it isn't clear that an ANOVA would be appropriate. How many measures do you have per mollusk?

Comment: The mucus data is already transformed because it was a ratio to begin with (mucus/dry mass ratio), and was transformed via arcsine. The mucus collection procedure is fatal, so it's one value per mollusk. The differences in the data sets arise from the number of mollusks that were able to be tested in each group. For example, the 50 ppb groups high the highest mortality rates, so I was only able to collect mucus from a handful in comparison to the 0 ppb groups

Comment: This is a very interesting question. In essence, you have informative missingness (NMAR data). BTW, I might question the arcsine transformation (cf, *The arcsine is asinine* ([pdf](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1890/10-0340.1/pdf))), note that a number of other possibilities exist. Did you sacrifice the animals at a series of timepoints to track the progression of the mucus proportion?

Comment: Animals were all sacrificed at the end of the respective experiments to try and maximize the amount of data for the experiment  (mucus wasn't the only thing I was testing for, just the source of this stats issue)

Comment: What I mean is, did you sacrifice, eg, 1/4 of each group at week 1, anther 1/4 at week 2, ..., the last 1/4 of each group at week 4, to see how the mucus production was changing over time as a result of the exposure to the copper solution?

Comment: No, all animals were sacrificed at the end of the experiment on the same day. This had to be done due to the high mortality rates for the higher concentrations. If specimens were sacrificed as I went along there was the potential to run out of specimens for the end.

Comment: OK. Was it possible to get mucus values for the ones that died? After all, they're dead anyway...  What kind of numbers are we talking about?  Is it possible you could post your data?

Comment: Mucus can be obtained from only living organisms, unfortunately. And my data set is 89 figures long in this case, which makes it kind of hard to post in the comments

Comment: If you click the light gray "edit" under `[nonparametric]` at the bottom left of your Q, you could post the numbers in the body of your question (if you wanted). I don't know if I can answer this, but someone might & real data would facilitate that. It's an interesting situation, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can rank-transform the data (e.g. replace each value by its order in the overall data set) and then use some procedure that supports unbalanced and heteroskedastic normally distributed data. See e.g. Akritas (JASA,1990). This work covers explicitly unbalanced two-way data, is nonparametric and even suitable for interactions.